# Какой подход используется для slugification на Хэшкод

Tags: slug, django

Посмотрел код OSQA. Так как это приложение на Джанго, оно использует `django.template.defaultfilters.slugify` для "слугификации" URL. Но эта функция плохо работает с не-ascii-символами (попросту удаляет).

Но - на [@Хэшкод](/users/1/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)'е все работает. Какой подход используете вы? Что-то универсальное или только для русского языка? Если универсальное - может, поделитесь подходом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делаем так:

```
def u_slugify(txt):
        txt = txt.strip()
        txt = re.sub('\s*-\s*','-', txt, flags=re.UNICODE) 
        txt = re.sub('[\s/]', '_', txt, flags=re.UNICODE) 
        txt = re.sub('(\d):(\d)', r'\1-\2', txt, flags=re.UNICODE)
        txt = re.sub('"', "'", txt, flags=re.UNICODE)
        txt = re.sub(r'[?,:!@#~`+=$%^&\\*()\[\]{}<>]','',txt, flags=re.UNICODE) 
        return txt
```

Comment: Мы делаем также.

Comment: Оно не смотрит на свойства символов и смело пропустит, скажем, U+200B. Последнюю замену я бы предложил сделать в духе `txt = re.sub(r"(?u)[^\w_-]", "", txt)`.

И, это, в приведенном коде `re.UNICODE` ошибочно, т.к. попадает на место `count`, а не `flags`. Следует или использовать `(?u)` или `flags=re.UNICODE`.

Answer (score 3):

Из рекомендаций по **Flask**'у (с транслитерацией):

```
import re

from unidecode import unidecode  # ставится отдельно: pip install unidecode
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = Library()

PUNCT_RE = re.compile(r'[\t !"#$%&\'()*\-/<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|},.]+')

@stringfilter
def slugify(text, delim=u'-'):
    """Generates an ASCII-only slug."""
    result = []
    for word in PUNCT_RE.split(text.lower()):
        result.extend(unidecode(word).split())
    return mark_safe(unicode(delim.join(result)))

slugify.is_safe = True
```

Comment: Да, unidecode я уже нашел, но [в нашем случае](https://github.com/ametaireau/pelican/issues/332) он вроде как не совсем подходит

Comment: Не понял какая у Вас там возникает ошибка, но я привёл код с боевого сервера - используется здесь http://tunoid.com (щёлкните на верхнее левое объявление чтоб увидеть пример слугификации).

Comment: Дело не в ошибке. Дело в слугификации. Транслитерация не устраивает